# I get error " No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation"

Tags: android, android-espresso, androidx

I get error "No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation" when I try to run SignUpFragmentTest class. I think thaterror is thrown when I use @Rule.

```
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;



import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;



@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

public class SignUpFragmentTest {

    @Rule public final ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> main = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    private LoginActivity mActivity = null;



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mActivity =main.getActivity();
    }
    @Test
    public void testLaunchSingUpScreen(){
        FrameLayout frameLayout = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        assertNotNull(frameLayout);
        Fragment fragment = new SignUpFragment();
        mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frameLayout.getId(),fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mActivity= null;
    }
}
```

I add to dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
```

and

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

to  defaultConfig

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is to completely change ALL libraries back from

```
androidX
```

to

```
com.android.support
```

libraries in the build.gradle

Please note: You might have to re import the libraries in test your class e.g.

```
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;
```

to

```
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;
```

Also make sure you always clean and rebuilt the project after each addition or removal library from build.gradle.